# Cloud Code: HTTPResponse status code 302

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying this POST function in Parse Cloud and its throwing error with http response code 302. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://siteabcd.com/auth.action',
        body: {
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            button: 'Login',
        },  
        headers: {
            'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2"
        },
        success: function(httpResponse){
            alert("response:"+httpResponse.text+"---header length:"+httpResponse.headers.length);
                response.success("Message Sent");
        },
        error: function(httpResponse){
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            response.error("Message Not Sent");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`302` means the URL makes a redirect:

https://www.parse.com/questions/httprequest-request-failed-with-response-code-302

https://parse.com/questions/cloud-code-httpresponse-status-code-302

Answer (score 2):

As @dimitri points out `302` means redirect. For example if you go to `http://google.com` in Sweden Google will most likely send a 302 response at first and then go to `http://google.se`. It could also be that the domain redirects from `http` version to a `https` or similar.

Parse doesn't support redirects yet in their sdk. The easiest way to solve this until they do is to look at the Location header in the 302 response `res.get('Location');` and update the url you are sending the request to accordingly.